# Mercurial HGWeb not working with UNC path on windows

Tags: windows, mercurial

I have recently started moving some HG repos to a network drive. The HG web setup worked perfectly when the repos were on the local drive.

**Old Setup:**

> - C:\Repos\repo1
> - C:\Repos\repo2
>
> the hgweb.conf had the following:
>
> [paths]
>      / = C:/Repos/*

---

**New Setup:**

> - //storage/repos/repo1
> - //storage/repos/repo2
>
> the hgweb.conf has the following:
>
> [paths]
>      / = //storage/repos/*

---

When I then browse hgweb, none of my repositories show up in the list (the page renders fine, just no repos listed).

I have tried every combination of / and \ to no avail.

I don't think this is a permission problem as I have looked though filemon, and mercurial IS finding the paths, and reading the .hg directory for each. It's just not displaying them on the web.

I have also tried mounting the network path to a drive letter, and that also doesn't work.

Any help greatly appreciated =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just FYI, the problem with this was to do with the username that the Apache2 service was running under. Setting that up with a user that had permission to access the network path fixed the issue.